# How to write OnPlatform code for RelativeLayout ConstraintExpression

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on `RelativeLayout`. I want to provide `ConstraintExpression` for `X,Y, Width and Height` separate for iOS and Anroid.

How can I do that for below code

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AttendanceType }"
    TitleColor="Black" Title="--Select--"   
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.9}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.05}"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=22}"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.28}">
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work using the "compressed" onplatform syntax for xaml:

```
    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AttendanceType }"
            TitleColor="Black" Title="--Select--"   
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor={OnPlatform Android=.9, iOS=.8}}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor={OnPlatform Android=.05, iOS=.04}}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor={OnPlatform Android=0, iOS=1},Constant={OnPlatform Android=22, iOS=21}}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor={OnPlatform Android=.28, iOS=.27}}">
    </Picker>
```

More info about the markup extension here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onplatform-markup-extension